# Maven Site Plugin fails with :Could not access java.util.EnumSet.elementType

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-2, xstream, maven-site-plugin

I use maven site plugin version 2.2 and XStream version 1.3.1. When I do,

```
mvn site:stage -DstagingDirectory=C:\
```

It always fails with

```
[INFO] Trace
com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InitializationException: Could not instatiate converter : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.enums.EnumSetConverter : null
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:651)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:620)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:371)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.dashboard.report.plugin.DashBoardUtils.saveXMLDashBoardReport(DashBoardUtils.java:995)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.dashboard.report.plugin.DashBoardReportMojo.executeReport(DashBoardReportMojo.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteStageMojo.execute(SiteStageMojo.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:515)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:644)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not access java.util.EnumSet.elementType field
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.find(Fields.java:18)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.enums.EnumSetConverter.<init>(EnumSetConverter.java:31)
        ... 36 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 11 17:01:09 CDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 118M/249M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm doing wrong here. I tried to use XStream version 1.2.2 without any luck

Comment: Wow.  This same issue was causing my Launch4j application not to work on Windows 7 64-bit (6.1 build 7601) - it worked on Windows XP Professional 32-bit though.  I followed your comment's suggestion and upgraded to the latest XStream (and replaced the xstream.jar in Launch4j's lib folder) and my issue disappeared.  +1 for making my life easier!

Answer (score 1):

From exception that is Dashboard Maven Plugin that fails. Try using different version of that.

Comment: Checked out the source code of dashboard plugin and realized it was using version 1.2 of XStream which had this defect. So changed the dependency of the Xstream to 1.3.1 and created a new artifact for dashboard plugin. That solved the issue.